# C++ : elegantly iterate a set of numbers

Tags: c++, loops, c++11, c++14

Could anyone suggest how in C++11/14 to elegantly iterate a constant set (in english meaning, not C++ meaning) of numbers, preferably without leaving temporary objects like here:

```
set<int> colors;
colors.insert(0);
colors.insert(2);

for (auto color : colors)
{
    //Do the work
}
```

? Hope to find a 1-liner.

In other words, is there a magical way to make it look somewhat like this:

```
for (int color in [0,2])//reminds me of Turbo Pascal
{
    //Do the work
}
```

or

```
for (auto color in set<int>(0,2))//Surely it cannot work this way as it is
{
    //Do the work
}
```

Comment: What you are iterating is a set of integers. It would be an equal or larger overhead to iterate using references. What you have is fine.

Comment: Which object are you talking about when you say *temporary objects like here*?

Comment: `for (auto const &color : colors)`, for instance, is valid.

Comment: I am looking for a way to make the source code elegant and avoid introducing "colors".

Comment: `set` serves no apparent purpose here given your values are known; `for (auto color : {0, 2})` is fine.

Comment: A [`std::integer_sequence`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/integer_sequence) is probably what you want. It's totally compile-time evaluated and will not incur any run-time overhead.

Comment: @ildjarn  for (auto color : {0, 2}) - this one is perfect and as elegant as one can get. Could you make it an answer?

Comment: @BarsMonster : As it is now, your question is very `std::set`-centric, and `{0, 2}` in that context is a `std::initializer_list`, so it really isn't an answer. Fix your question first. ;-]

Comment: @ildjarn Hopefully done

Comment: @BarsMonster, what's the exact meaning of _elegant_.  You have used several times in your exposition and I think it is the nucleus of your question.  But _elegant_ deserves some explanation yet.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `std::initializer_list` instead of a `std::set`:

```
for (auto color : {2, 5, 7, 3}) {
    // Magic
}
```

The enclosed braces `{ ... }` will deduce an `std::initializer_list<int>`, which is iterable.

Answer (score 1):

Just some random thoughts.
Something like this?

```
for(auto color : set<int>{0, 2}) { // do the work }
```

Or maybe use a function?

```
auto worker = [](int x) { // do the work };
worker(0);
worker(2);
```

To avoid temporary object, maybe use templated function like

```
template<int N>
void worker(params_list) {
   // do the work
}
```

then

```
worker<0>(params_list);
worker<2>(params_list);
```